# Python Flask applicatoin sharing global variable across threads

Tags: python, flask, thread-safety, uwsgi

I have a Python Flask application, which on startup parse/load large data file into memory and exposes REST API for querying (read-only) the in-memory data.
This works perfect if I set uwsgi to spawn 1 process and 1 thread. But when I set "threads = 10" in the wsgi.ini file, the REST APIs are just hanging.

How can I share a global variable as read-only across Flask worker threads?

My code is like:
`def create_app():
app = Flask(**name**)

```
config.read_config() # Load the configuration settings
log_file = config.SETTINGS['LOG_PATH']
logging_format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s'

fh = RotatingFileHandler(log_file, maxBytes=config.SETTINGS['LOG_SIZE'], backupCount=2)
logging.basicConfig(
    level=config.SETTINGS["LOG_LEVEL"],
    format=logging_format,
    handlers=[fh, logging.StreamHandler()])
logging.info("Service started!")

in_memory_data = load_in_mem_data()

with app.app_context():

    @app.route('/rest/get methods=['GET'])
    def get_data():
        result = filter_data(in_memory_data)
        return jsonify(result)
```

`

The size of data in memory is 10GB. I cannot have copy per thread.
This data need to be shared only between threads and not required across processes.
My application has low-latency requirements.

Can flask current_app help here?

I also need all threads write to common log file.